# Peculiar output while displaying Linked list in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, singly-linked-list

Whenever I try to display my linked list, this got displayed on the compiler (compiled in Spyder(Python 3.0))

```
    <bound method Kernel.raw_input of <spyder_kernels.console.kernel.SpyderKernel object at 0x000002433E588A30>>--><bound method Kernel.raw_input of <spyder_kernels.console.kernel.SpyderKernel object at 0x000002433E588A30>>-->
```

Here is my compilations:

```
In [11]: runfile('C:/Users/singh/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/singh/.spyder-py3')

no of nodes: 2

Enter the 1 node data: 12

Enter the 2 node data: 1
<bound method Kernel.raw_input of <spyder_kernels.console.kernel.SpyderKernel object at 0x000002433E588A30>>--><bound method Kernel.raw_input of <spyder_kernels.console.kernel.SpyderKernel object at 0x000002433E588A30>>-->

In [12]:
```

Here is the code for creating and displaying linked list:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

class node:
    def __init__ (self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        
class linkedlist:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.head = None
    
    def insertAtfront (self, data):
        n = node(data, self.head)
        self.head = n
    
    def display (self):
        if self.head is None:
            print('linked list is empty')
            return
        
        itr = self.head
        s = ''
        while itr is not None:
            s += str(itr.data) + '-->'
            itr = itr.next
        print(s)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    llist = linkedlist()
    no = int(input("no of nodes: "))
    for i in range(no):
        intput = int(input('Enter the {} node data: '.format(i+1)))
        llist.insertAtfront(input)
    llist.display()
```

Please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: It looks to me like, you are printing the node objects rather than the contents of the node

Comment: You seem to have a simple typo in your reading loop; you're passing `input` instead of `intput` to `llist.insertAtfront`.